# Unique Hashtags Counter

Tags: java, hashtag

I was looking at this code and I was wondering what's the best way to change the output to state the number of hashtags instead of what the hashtags are? Like if you input #one #two blue red #one #green four #jaja hg instead of getting a output of [#one, #two, #jaja, #green] you would get a output of [4]

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class HashTags {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a line of text");
        String tweet = scanner.nextLine();
        Set<String> hashtags = getHashtags(tweet);      
        System.out.println(hashtags.toString());
    }

    public static Set<String> getHashtags(String tweet) {
        String[] words = tweet.split(" ");
        Set<String> hashtags = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.startsWith("#")) {
                hashtags.add(word);
            }
        }
        return hashtags;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the javadoc of `Set`. Is there a method that gives you the _size_ by any chance?

Comment: Also, as an aside, `System.out.println()` automatically calls the `toString()` method of the `Object` you input, so you can save yourself some typing and leave it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Set#size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#size%28%29)

```
System.out.println(hashtags.size());
```

Comment: Why did you add `Integer.toString()`?

Comment: I suppose that's not necessary. Just habit when displaying strings. I'll edit.